# Is there a way to let CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION also get called when libcurl sends a data?

Tags: c++, libcurl

According to libcurl manual, we know that CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION is gonna get called when it received data, which is from response header. I'd like to ask is there a way to let it also receive the request header data when there's one being sent ?  I'm using C++ libcurl.

Edit : It's something like CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT in libcurl php, but I'm not sure if c++ also get the similar option. btw, I realized I can use CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION to enable CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, but I'm not allowed to call this callback in my production code, so I need to figure out another way.

Thank you !

Comment: I see no such option available in the [list of supported options](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html).

Comment: I saw no way from that page either, just hope to make sure I'm not missing anything.